# How to do a pandas sample on more than one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about 8 million observations. I need to pull a sample from that, but would like to sample from more than one column.

I've tried the following which does not work:

```
import pandas as pd

state = ['mi', 'mi', 'mi', 'nc', 'pa', 'pa', 'ga']
state = state * 50
age = ['21', '22', '23', '23', '23', '50', '50']
age = age * 50
random = ['.445', '.324', '.234', '.143', '.568', '.777', '.256']
random = random * 50
data = {'state':state, 'age': age, 'random': random}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data = data)

df_sample = df.sample(n = 25, weights = ['state', 'age'], random_state = 48)
```

I realize the `pandas` docs does not state what I want to do is possible.  Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: `df_sample = df[['state','age']].sample(n = 25, random_state = 48)` ?

Comment: seems to work.  If you put up as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

I think you are looking to achieve the following:

```
df_sample = df[['state','age']].sample(n = 25, random_state = 48)
```